# Two one-tailed fisher's tests versus two-tailed test

Tags: fishers-exact-test

I have a 2x2 contingency table on which I would like to perform a two-tailed fisher test. However, the stats library that I am using only lets me do a one-tailed fisher test for the "greater" alternative hypothesis.

Thus, my plan is to obtain the results for a two-tailed test by:

1. Performing the one-tailed test on the real data (for "greater")
2. Reversing the contingency table (essentially swapping the columns) and performing the one-tailed test again (for "lesser")
3. Combining the results from both (-> two-tailed)
4. And finally multiplying all p-values from these tests by 2 to account for the fact that I just performed two tests.

Is this a valid approach? I think it should be equivalent to performing a single two-sided test, but I am not sure whether it doesn't violate some underlying assumptions.